# Turning off ActiveSupport::Subscribers / Notifications

Tags: performance, activerecord, sinatra, activesupport

I'm using [stackprof](https://github.com/tmm1/stackprof) to profile a sinatra application which uses Active Record. When I inspect the output of the generated files, I get the following:

```
[vagrant@localhost vagrant]$ bin/stackprof tmp/stackprof-cpu-5754-1468440335.dump --text --limit 10
==================================
  Mode: cpu(1000)
  Samples: 146 (1.35% miss rate)
  GC: 7 (4.79%)
==================================
 TOTAL    (pct)     SAMPLES    (pct)     FRAME
    19  (13.0%)          18  (12.3%)     ActiveSupport::Subscriber#start
    10   (6.8%)          10   (6.8%)     ActiveRecord::Timestamp#current_time_from_proper_timezone
    13   (8.9%)           9   (6.2%)     Logger#add
   285 (195.2%)           5   (3.4%)     Statsd#time
     5   (3.4%)           5   (3.4%)     block in ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::AbstractMysqlAdapter#execute
     6   (4.1%)           5   (3.4%)     ActiveRecord::LazyAttributeHash#[]
    12   (8.2%)           5   (3.4%)     ActiveSupport::Subscriber#finish
     4   (2.7%)           4   (2.7%)     ActiveRecord::Relation#initialize_copy
     6   (4.1%)           4   (2.7%)     block (2 levels) in Class#class_attribute
     3   (2.1%)           3   (2.1%)     Logger::Formatter#format_datetime
```

When I subscribe and log the notifications, they are simply AR query notifications, which I don't care about at the moment.

It also appears that ActiveSupport::Subscribers / notifications are a performance bottleneck. Is there a way to disable turn these via an ActiveSupport configuration?